# NGINX Configs guidance needed for socket.io

Tags: nginx, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis

The codes below are under my sites-enabled folder in nginx ..
however, the lines where i "add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';" and add_header "'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';" after the if statements are causing my socket to have multiple headers. can i seek suggestions to work around this ?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name devapi.doctoroneworld.com;


    location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000
       add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
       add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
       return 204;
       }
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, If-Modified-Since, Authorization';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';

proxy_set_header Content-Type 'application/json';

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

Comment: How is that related to sockets?

Comment: @sturcotte06 ""add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';" and add_header "'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';" after the if statements are causing my socket to have multiple headers. can i seek suggestions to work around this "

Comment: "[...] are causing my *requests* to have multiple headers. Your socket has a source address, a destination address and other properties but it doesn't have any headers. A socket is agnostic to the protocol, which is http in your case.

Comment: @sturcotte06 sorry i dont really get you, but if you're refering to why my socket has headers in the first place, i think its because of the engine.io in sock.io that is adding in headers as well. =[

Comment: @sturcotte06 im not really good with regex but im trying to make a regex that looks if the request has no /socket.io at the end so that THEN i would add a header.. any help ?

Comment: `(?:\/socket\.io\/?)$` https://regex101.com/r/tO9zyZ/1

Comment: @sturcotte06 is this valid ?  
        if ($http_url !~ '^.*[^socket.io-client]') {
        set $cors 'true';
        }
cause i can't seem to compile it lol

Comment: @sturcotte06 Thank you ! i've managed to go about it . thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

this is what I've added in the above code : and i commented out the add_headers that were affecting the socket requests

```
set $cors '';
    if ($request_uri !~ '^/socket.io-client') {
    set $cors 'true';
    }

    if ($cors = 'true') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    }
```